# Hexchat cannot accept SSL

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, irc, xchat

I've been trying to access an IRC Server recently, which I have been on before. I can access it on Windows but when I get into Ubuntu I cannot access it due to not being able to "Use SSl for all the servers on this network" and "Accept invalid SSL certificates"

I cannot work out why I cannot check both of those options. I've had a look round and cannot seem to find anyone else with the issue.

Screen shot of what I am describing below.

[http://i.imgur.com/4i8ouJh.png](https://i.imgur.com/4i8ouJh.png)

Ignore the server address and usernames, that's purely for privacy purposes.

Comment: Where did you get Hexchat from? Ubuntu’s official repositories? It might have been built without SSL support.

Comment: I cannot remember, I could try downloading it from somewhere else.

Comment: managed to get it to work, I had done a work around before because for some reason I couldn't get it to download via apt-get install hexchat, it was trying to download the dependencies for Ubuntu 12.04. but I found the package manager from the creator of Hexchat and added it directly into my /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: Congrats. You should add an answer explaining what you did. After a day you can then accept your own answer.